# Primefaces datatable hasn't been refreshed after applying the filter

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have some code is similar to the following showcase:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml

The filter is applied correctly in the backing bean, although the datatable hasn't been refreshed with the new filtered rows. It remains as it is before applying the filter. Is there something missing or wrong in this showcase?

```
        <h:form>
        <p:dataTable var="serviceEntity" value="#{serviceSearchMB.allServices}" widgetVar="serviceSearchTable"
            emptyMessage="No services found with given criteria" filteredValue="#{serviceSearchMB.filteredServices}">

            <f:facet name="header">

                    <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('serviceSearchTable').filter();"
                        style="width:150px" placeholder="Enter keyword" />

            </f:facet>


            <p:column filterBy="#{serviceEntity.serviceName}" headerText="Service Name" filterMatchMode="contains" >

                <h:outputText value="#{serviceEntity.serviceName}" />
            </p:column>
...
```

Backing Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="serviceSearchMB")
@RequestScoped
public class ServiceSearchManagedBean implements Serializable {
    private List<ServiceSearchEntity> filteredServices;


    public List<ServiceSearchEntity> getFilteredServices() {
        return filteredServices;
    }


    public void setFilteredServices(List<ServiceSearchEntity> filteredServices) {
        this.filteredServices = filteredServices; // Already set the filtered list correctly.
    }

    public List<ServiceSearchEntity> getAllServices() {
        //already returns all services.
    }
...
```

Comment: add backing bean code

Comment: @meyquel PF version 5.1.. and I've added backing bean code.. and I've edited the code in the xhtml page little bit.

Comment: showcase is ok, can you show all xhtml code...